# Continuous maps on topological spaces with deleted point

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $x \in X$ with $x$ closed in the topology on $X$.
Let $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous map.

My question is, what are the necessary requirements on $f$ so that $f(X \setminus {x}) = f(X) \setminus f(x)$.

I originally thought that $f$ must be bijective, but i am not 100% sure.

Thank you for your help although this may be a trivial question.

Comment: Well... The necessary and sufficient condition that there shouldn't be some $y\ne x$ such that $f(x)= f(y)$ seems quite primitive to me.

Comment: See for instance $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, $f(t)=t^2$ and $x=0$. Topologically you have everything you could wish for, but I don't see how this is relevant.

Comment: Note that [half of the desired equality](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Image_of_Set_Difference_under_Mapping) is automatic for arbitrary maps on sets.  The remaining half is equivalent to $f(x) \not \in f(X \smallsetminus x)$.